# Kafka SASL_SSL Authentication error, how authenticate?

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, apache-kafka, apache-beam

I'm working in Java with a pipeline that consumes data from a Kafka Cluster, it's
available on

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-google-examples/blob/master/ccloud-dataflow-demo/entry-df-pipeline/src/main/java/com/ecuevas/DataflowPipeline.java

According to the repository, the `props` and `pipeline` are defined:

```
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
        props.put("ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "https");
        props.put("sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN");
        props.put("request.timeout.ms", 20000);
        props.put("retry.backoff.ms", 500);
        props.put("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL");
        props.put("sasl.jaas.config",String.format("org.apache.kafka.common.security.
        plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"%s\" password=\"%s\";",username, password));

        LogKafkaMsg logKafkaMsg = new LogKafkaMsg();

        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

        PCollection<KV<String, String>> entries =
                pipeline
                        .apply(
                                "Read Entries from Confluent Cloud Topic",
                                KafkaIO.<String, String>read()
                                        .withBootstrapServers("<your-bootstrap-server>")
                                        .withTopic("entries")
                                        .withConsumerConfigUpdates(props)
                                        .withKeyDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
                                        .withValueDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
                                        .withoutMetadata()
                        );
```

My problem is when the code is executed, returns the following error:

```
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:969)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:198)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:322)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:308)
        at com.ecuevas.DataflowPipeline.main(DataflowPipeline.java:214)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SaslAuthenticationException: Invalid SASL/PLAIN response: expected 3 tokens, got 4
```

Probably the issue is related with the SASL/PLAIN authentication, but I don't know a possible solution. I think that is related with:

- SSL authentication: Include `ca-cert`, `ca-key`, `ca-password` or another special.
- Dependencies updates: The libraries versions aren't updated.

Comment: I'd suggest opening a github issue or tagging the person that wrote the linked example saying it doesn't work anymore... That being said, Confluent Cloud interface should provide you all the necessary client information to connect with

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Dataflow VMs are not authenticated to connect to the Kafka cluster.  Have you tried authenticating using a keystore certificate file per instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54337653/connect-to-kafka-with-ssl-using-kafkaio-on-google-dataflow) ?