# Google dataflow JDBCIO passing SSL certificate using Java?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to pass the SSL certificate to the connection properties in JDBCIO. read() and I keep getting the error
"No such file or directory exists - /tmp/.jks"

What I have tried - I have a class that reads the .jks file from my GCS bucket and then writes it to local file system - /tmp/.jks file.

I am then passing /tmp/.jks file path as SSLTrustStorePath=/tmp/.jks;SSLTrustPassword=1234AB

Can someone please help me resolve this issue.

```
 pipeline.apply("Read from JDBC presto", JdbcIO.<TableRow>read().withDataSourceConfiguration(
                    JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create(JDBC_DRIVER, jdbcUrl)
                            .withUsername("username")
                            .withPassword("pswd").withConnectionProperties(new ConsumerFactoryFn().apply("")))
                    .withQuery("select * from tablename")
                    .withCoder(TableRowJsonCoder.of())
                    .withRowMapper(new JdbcIO.RowMapper<TableRow>() {
                        public TableRow mapRow(ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception {

                            ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
                            TableRow outputTableRow = new TableRow();
                            for (int i = 1; i <= resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                                outputTableRow.set(resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(i), resultSet.getObject(i));
                        }
                        return outputTableRow;
                    }
                })).apply("Write to BigQuery",
                        BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                                .withoutValidation()
                                .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
                                .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                                .to("projectID:dataset.tablename"));
```

This is in the ConsumerFactoryFn

```
public String apply(String input) {
        try {
            Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
            Blob blob = storage.get("bucketname", "certificate.jks");
            ReadChannel readChannel = blob.reader();
            FileOutputStream fileOuputStream;
            fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/filename.jks"); // path where the jks file will be
                                                                                    // stored
            fileOuputStream.getChannel().transferFrom(readChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
            fileOuputStream.close();
            File f = new File("/tmp/filename.jks"); // assuring the store file exists
            if (f.exists()) {
                logger.info("key exists");

            } else {
                logger.warn("key does not exist");

            }
           File file = Files.createTempDir().createTempFile("filename",".jks", f);
            logger.info("file name is"+file.getAbsolutePath());

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }

        input = "SSLTrustStorePath=/tmp/filename.jks;SSLTrustStorePassword=pswd";

        return input;
    }
```

Comment: Tried everything in this solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54337653/connect-to-kafka-with-ssl-using-kafkaio-on-google-dataflow and still getting the same error.

Comment: Could you share your source code?

Comment: @ningk I added the source code in my question.