# Unable to connect from Dataflow job to Schema Registry when Schema Registry requires TLS client authentication

Tags: apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, confluent-schema-registry

I am developing a GCP Cloud Dataflow job that use Kafka broker and Schema Registry.
Our Kafka broker and Schema Registry requires TLS client certificate.
And I am facing connection issue with Schema Registry on deployment. 
Any suggestion is highly welcomed.

Here is what I do for the Dataflow job.
I create Consumer Properties for TLS configurations.

```
props.put("security.protocol", "SSL");
props.put("ssl.truststore.password", "aaa");
props.put("ssl.keystore.password", "bbb");
props.put("ssl.key.password", "ccc"));
props.put("schema.registry.url", "https://host:port")
props.put("specific.avro.reader", true);
```

And update Consumer Properties by updateConsumerProperties.

```
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options)
...
.updateConsumerProperties(properties)
...
```

As this stackoverflow answer suggests, I also download keyStore and trustStore to local directory and specify trustStore / keyStore location on ConsumerProperties in ConsumerFactory.

[Truststore and Google Cloud Dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726011/truststore-and-google-cloud-dataflow)

```
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options)
 ...
 .withConsumerFactoryFn(new MyConsumerFactory(...))
 ...
```

In ConsumerFactory:

```
public Consumer<byte[], byte[]> apply(Map<String, Object> config)  {
  // download keyStore and trustStore from GCS bucket 
  config.put("ssl.truststore.location", (Object)localTrustStoreFilePath)
  config.put("ssl.keystore.location", (Object)localKeyStoreFilePath)
  new KafkaConsumer<byte[], byte[]>(config);
}
```

With this code I succeeded in deployment but the Dataflow job got TLS server certificate verification error.

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
        sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
        sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
        sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
        java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
        sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
        io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:208)
        io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:252)
        io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:482)
        io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:475)
        io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaByIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:151)
        io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getBySubjectAndId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:230)
        io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getById(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:209)
        io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:116)
        io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:88)
        org.fastretailing.rfid.store.siv.EPCTransactionKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(EPCTransactionKafkaAvroDeserializer.scala:14)
        org.fastretailing.rfid.store.siv.EPCTransactionKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(EPCTransactionKafkaAvroDeserializer.scala:7)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaUnboundedReader.advance(KafkaUnboundedReader.java:234)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaUnboundedReader.start(KafkaUnboundedReader.java:176)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources$UnboundedReaderIterator.start(WorkerCustomSources.java:779)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation$SynchronizedReaderIterator.start(ReadOperation.java:361)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:194)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:76)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1228)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:143)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:967)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Then I found that Schema Registry client load TLS configurations from system property.
https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues/943

I tested Kafka Consumer with the same configuration, and I confirmed it works fine.

```
props.put("schema.registry.url", "https://host:port")
props.put("specific.avro.reader", true);
props.put("ssl.truststore.location", System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore"));
props.put("ssl.truststore.password", System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore"));
props.put("ssl.keystore.location", System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore"));
props.put("ssl.keystore.password", System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword"));
props.put("ssl.key.password", System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.key.password"));
```

Next I applied the same approach, which means apply the same TLS configurations to  system properties and Consumer Properties, to Dataflow job code.

I specified password by system properties when executing application.

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=aaa \
-Djavax.net.ssl.key.password=bbb \
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=ccc \
```

Note: I set system property for trustStore and keyStore location in Consumer Factory since those files are downloaded to local temp directory.

```
config.put("ssl.truststore.location", (Object)localTrustStoreFilePath)
config.put("ssl.keystore.location", (Object)localKeyStoreFilePath)
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", localTrustStoreFilePath)
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", localKeyStoreFilePath)
```

but even deployment was failed with timeout error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to construct instance from factory method DataflowRunner#fromOptions(interface org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:224)
...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataflowRunner requires gcpTempLocation, but failed to retrieve a value from PipelineOptions
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions(DataflowRunner.java:246)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error constructing default value for gcpTempLocation: tempLocation is not a valid GCS path, gs://dev-k8s-rfid-store-dataflow/rfid-store-siv-epc-transactions-to-bq/tmp. 
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create(GcpOptions.java:255)
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to verify that GCS bucket gs://dev-k8s-rfid-store-dataflow exists.
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.verifyPathIsAccessible(GcsPathValidator.java:86)
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:401)
...
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
        at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.throwException(SSLSocketFactory.java:248)
...
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
        at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1617)
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:780)
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:778)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: got the same error even if directly specified passwords. So "System.setProperty" in Consumer Factory might not work well as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got reply from GCP support. It seems that Apache Beam does not support Schema Registry.

> Hello,
> the Dataflow specialist has reached me back. I will now expose what they have told me.
>
> The answer to your question is no, Apache Beam does not support Schema Registry.
> However, they have told me that you could implement the calls to Schema Registry
> by yourself as Beam only consumes raw messages and it is user's responsibility to do
> whatever they need with the data.
>
> This is based on our understanding of the case that you want to publish messages to Kafka,
> and have DF consume those messages, parsing them based on the schema from the registry.
>
> I hope this information can be useful to you, let me know if I can be of further help.

But Dataflow job can still receive Avro format binary message. So you internally call Schema Registry REST API as follows.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55917157

Comment: is this still true in 2022?

Answer (score 1):

In the `ConsumerFactoryFn`, you need to copy the certificate from some location (such as GCS) to a local file path on the machine.

In [Truststore and Google Cloud Dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726011/truststore-and-google-cloud-dataflow?noredirect=1&lq=1), the `ConsumerFnFactory` that the user writes has this snippet of code which fetches the truststore from GCS:

```
            Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
                    .setProjectId("prj-id-of-your-bucket")
                    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault())
                    .build()
                    .getService();
            Blob blob = storage.get("your-bucket-name", "pth.to.your.kafka.client.truststore.jks");
            ReadChannel readChannel = blob.reader();
            FileOutputStream fileOuputStream;
            fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/kafka.client.truststore.jks"); //path where the jks file will be stored
            fileOuputStream.getChannel().transferFrom(readChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
            fileOuputStream.close();
            File f = new File("/tmp/kafka.client.truststore.jks"); //assuring the store file exists
            if (f.exists())
            {
                LOG.debug("key exists");

            }
            else
            {
                LOG.error("key does not exist");

            }
```

You'll need to do something similar (it doesn't have to be GCS but it does need to be accessible from all VMs executing your pipeline on Google Cloud Dataflow).

Comment: Thanks but I already did it. it seems that Apache beam does not support schema registry. I will post it after I get answer from GCP support.